# how to deal with mongodb race condition in integration test

Tags: mongodb, express, concurrency

I have a mongoose schema with a unique field and I am trying to write a backend (express) integration test which checks that POSTing the same entity twice results in HTTP 400. When testing manually behaviour is as excpected. Automatic testing however requires a wait:

```
it('should not accept two projects with the same name', function(done) {
  var project = // ...
  postProjectExpect201(project,
                       () => {
                         setTimeout( () => {
                           postProjectExpect400(project, done);
                         },100);
                       }
                      );
});
```

The two post... methods do as named and the code above works fine, but if the timeout is removed, BOTH requests receive HTTP 200 (though only one entity created in the database).

I'm new to those technologies and I'm not sure what's going on. Could this be a mongodb related concurrency issue and if so how should I deal with it?

The database call looks like this:

```
Project.create(req.body)
.then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
.catch(next);
```

I already tried connecting to mongodb with ?w=1 option btw.

**Update**:

To be more verbose: *Project* is a mongoose model and *next* is my express error handler which catches the duplicate error.

The test functions:

```
var postProjectExpect201=function(project, done, validateProject) {
  request(app)
  .post('/api/projects')
  .send(project)
  .expect(201)
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .end((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    validateProject && validateProject(res.body);
    done();
  });
};

var postProjectExpect400=function(project, done) {
  request(app)
  .post('/api/projects')
  .send(project)
  .expect(400)
  .end((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    done();
  });
};
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not checking the writeresult of the insert: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#writeresults-insert

Comment: How about sharing the actual code. It is more likely that you, being new, made a mistake than that you found a race condition nobody found so far. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: @PureW mongoose should be doing that for me, right?

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg I now included the missing test code. As stated the test breaks if the timeout is removed, so there's a race condition (not necessarily a bug).

Comment: Can't reproduce after restart, so this can be closed.